# how to sign in automatically using sharedpreferences in android

Tags: java, android, authentication, sharedpreferences

i have splash activity that will be directed to login activity, if login is true, then the user will be direct to home, but when the user press back in home, application will be closing automatically.
but the problem is when user open  application, they must be login again, even they not logout before. so how to direct splash into home activity? i have read, to handle it i must used sharedpreferences so i have to used it, but i don't how to handle login automatically using it.
this is my spash:

```
public class SplashEpolicy extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //hide title bar
    BasicDisplaySettings.toggleTaskBar(SplashEpolicy.this, false);
    //show status bar
    BasicDisplaySettings.toggleStatusBar(SplashEpolicy.this, true);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_epolicy);

    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //this is configuration for how long the splash will be shown.
                //
                int time = Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.splashTransTime));
                sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //line below is for direct new activity that will be run after 
                //current activity finished.
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashEpolicy.this,EpolicyMainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);      
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();      
}
```

this is my login activity that containing sharedpreferences:

```
                String KEY = jo.getString("key");
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("etUser", strUser);
                editor.putString("key",KEY);
                editor.commit();
                System.out.println(KEY+""+"key"+""+"etUser");

                Dialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,EpolicyMainTab.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

so this is my Home (EpolicyListPolisActivity):

```
    public class EpolicyListPolis extends ListActivity {
    static String PEMEGANG="PEMEGANG";
    static String POLIS="POLIS";
    static String STATUS="STATUS";
    static String TERTANGGUNG="TERTANGGUNG";
    String KEY, strUser;
    List NasabahList= new ArrayList();
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    private String strStoragePath = "",
            strNameFileDiv = "";
    ImageView LogoutButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.Nomor_Polis);


        setContentView(R.layout.epolicy_list_polis);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
        strUser= settings.getString("etUser", null);
        KEY = settings.getString("key", null);
        LogoutButton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.LogoutButton);

        new NasabahAsyncTask().execute();

        LogoutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogSignOut();
            }
        });
            }
public class NasabahAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    String url = ("http://www.example.com?i="+strUser+"&k="+KEY);
    public NasabahAsyncTask() {
        this.url=url;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();   
        Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(EpolicyListPolis.this, "", "Melakukan Pengambilan Data");
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String result="";
    try {
        result=Connection.get(url);
    }catch (Exception e){
        result=" ";
        Log.d("test viewer",e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    fetchResponse(result.replace("\n", "").trim());

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            EpolicyListPolis.this, NasabahList, R.layout.epolicy_polis_listitem,
            new String[] {POLIS, PEMEGANG, TERTANGGUNG, STATUS}, new int [] {R.id.polis, R.id.pemegang, R.id.tertanggung, R.id.status});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    Dialog.dismiss();
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String POLIS = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.polis)).getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("POLIS", POLIS);
            editor.commit();
            }
}

private void fetchResponse(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!result.equals("")) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if (jsonObject.has("PEMEGANG")) 
                    map.put("PEMEGANG", jsonObject.get("PEMEGANG").toString());
                if (jsonObject.has("POLIS")) 
                    map.put("POLIS", jsonObject.get("POLIS").toString());
                if (jsonObject.has("STATUS")) 
                    map.put("STATUS", jsonObject.get("STATUS").toString());
                if (jsonObject.has("TERTANGGUNG")) 
                    map.put("TERTANGGUNG", jsonObject.get("TERTANGGUNG").toString());
                NasabahList.add(map);
                System.out.println("json oke");
}
        }catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    dialogExit();
}
public void dialogExit()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("do you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Intent itSplashEnd = new Intent(EpolicyListPolis.this, SplashEnd.class);
                   //setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                   itSplashEnd.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                   itSplashEnd.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   startActivity(itSplashEnd);
                   finish();
                   System.exit(0);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void dialogSignOut()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Sign out?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // what will i do here?

                   Intent itSignOut = new Intent(EpolicyListPolis.this, EpolicyMainActivity.class);
                   itSignOut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   startActivity(itSignOut);
                   finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

    }
```

so how to sign in automatically into home without going to login activity again using sharedpreferences? and how to clear data that saved in sharedpreferences every time user sign out?

Answer (score 2):

To sign in automatically:

Check if login details are saved in `SharedPreferences`. If found, you can retrieve that value and login automatically.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String loginID = prefs.getString("LOGIN_ID", "");
String loginPWD = prefs.getString("LOGIN_PWD", "");

if (loginID.length()>0 && loginPWD.length()>0) {
     //YOUR LOGIN CODE
} else {
     //SHOW PROMPT FOR LOGIN DETAILS
}
```

To clear the data when sign out, you can use the below piece of code in your sign out command:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("LOGIN_ID", "");     //RESET TO DEFAULT VALUE
editor.putString("LOGIN_PWD", "");     //RESET TO DEFAULT VALUE
editor.commit();
```

Comment: login details have saved in sharedprefences, but when i re-open my apps, it will ask for login again, may be it because i direct my splash into login activity, so how to fix it? thanks

Comment: In login activity, you can put the above condition before displaying the fields. If the values are already present, just call your login method.

Comment: i want to make it my shared prefences  clear when i sign out.. not reset to default

Comment: What do you mean with making your shared prefrences clear? if you put a string containing nothing ( editor.putString("LOGIN_ID", "") ) what you actually are doing is "clearing" your data.

Comment: i found the solution from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910156/how-to-check-the-sharedpreferences-string-is-empty-or-null-android but thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is wrong with Gokul Nath answer, but let's try again.
You can check if user already logged in by a simple if. First you load your user data (let's suppose username and password):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.project.myProject", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedUser = "com.project.myProject.savedUser";
String user = prefs.getString(savedUser, "none"); // return "none" if user is not logged in
String savedPass = "com.project.myProject.savedPass";
String pass = prefs.getString(savedPass, "none");

if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("none") || pass.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
    // Show a log in dialog and/or other stuff to let user log in
} else {
    // Launch your main interface
}
```

This works if you launch the app for the first time or after a logout.
On logout you can clear all your SharedPreferences like this (N.B.: clear or reset SharedPreferences is the same for me):

```
YourActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("com.project.myProject", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
```

By doing this, if user launch again your app, he will have to log in again.

Another things that i saw in your code is this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashEpolicy.this,EpolicyMainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);      
finish();
```

I guess you addFlags on intent because when you press back button, your app go back in SplashEpolicy. If i'm right you can do better in your code, by adding this line "android:noHistory="true"" in your Manifest (if i'm wrong, skip this part of my answer):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.project.myProject.SplashEpolicy"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With this your splash activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it (cit. Android Dev site).

Comment: i found the solution from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910156/how-to-check-the-sharedpreferences-string-is-empty-or-null-android but thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean to keep a track of the login state, that is, true if logged in and false otherwise. You could check the value of this boolean variable at splash screen so that you open the login dialog just in case it is false.
Here is a simple way to store the above mentioned boolean:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("youPrefsFile", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();
```

And a simple way to get its value:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("youPrefsFile",0);
boolean isLoggedin = settings.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i still don't get it... in what class i must to declare it?

Comment: just place it in your login activity the same way you did with your etUser and key values. After that you just show the login stuff if its value is false (with a simple if clause)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using Shared Preferences.
use one boolean flag as

```
        boolean signedflag=false;
```

store this flag in shared preferences.

check this flag at the time of login if 'signedflag=false' then only store 'login detail(login name and password)' to shared preferences else use existing value.

and when u will logout clear your all shared-preference variable and make the signedflag=false again.

Answer (score 0):

Save the loggedInUser in shared preferences on successful login like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();
```

And check is logged in like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isLoggedIn = prefs.getString(isLoggedIn, false); // return "false" if user is not logged in

if (!isLoggedIn) {
    // Show a log in dialog and/or other stuff to let user log in
} else {
    // Launch your main interface
}
```