# Login check on every single click

Tags: android, json, restful-authentication, mobile-application

I have a listview which consist of image.Now i want to check whether user is logged in or not for every image click.

Here is an CustomStatusGrid.java:

package com.example.kalpesh.statuscollection.Status.Adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.kalpesh.statuscollection.LoginActivity.MY_PREFS_NAME;

/**
 * Created by Kalpesh on 12/9/2017.
 */

public class CustomStatusGrid extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<StatusFrmCatResponse_Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
protected static final SharedPreferences settings = null;


public CustomStatusGrid(Context c, ArrayList<StatusFrmCatResponse_Model> arrayList) {
    mContext = c;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;



}


public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arrayList.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_status, null);


        TextView txt_StatusName = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txt_StatusName);
        txt_StatusName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getStatusName());

        //TextView txt_status = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txt_StatusId);

        //final String StatusID =txt_status.toString();



        ImageView imageClick = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.ImgAddtoFav);

        imageClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {







            }



        });

    }

    else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

}

Here is an LoginActivity.java :

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
ArrayList<LoginUserResponse_Model> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;

private UserInfo userInfo;
private Session session;
private Button login;

public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
protected static final SharedPreferences settings = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    userInfo        = new UserInfo(this);

    login           = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    findViewById(R.id.link_Register).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //if user pressed on login
            //we will open the login screen
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

private void login(final String email, final String password){


    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
    final String password1 = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    //validating inputs
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
    {
        editTextUsername.setError("Please enter your Email");
        editTextUsername.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

   /* if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
        email.setError("Enter a valid email");
        email.requestFocus();
        return;
    }*/

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password1))
    {
        editTextPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";
    //progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
    // progressDialog.show();

    String URL = "http://api.statuscollection.in/api/login";
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject datajsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                LoginUserResponse_Model getDetailStatusModel= new LoginUserResponse_Model();
                getDetailStatusModel.setCostamarId(datajsonObject.getString("CostamarId"));
                getDetailStatusModel.setEmail(datajsonObject.getString("Email"));
                getDetailStatusModel.setPassword(datajsonObject.getString("Password"));

                String CostamarId = getDetailStatusModel.setCostamarId(datajsonObject.getString("CostamarId"));

                Log.wtf("LoginActivity", "CostamarId " + datajsonObject.getString("CostamarId"));
                Log.wtf("LoginActivity", "Email " + datajsonObject.getString("Email"));
                Log.wtf("LoginActivity", "Password " + datajsonObject.getString("Password"));
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You are Login Successfuly !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // String CID =arrayList.get(CostamarId);

                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("logged", true);
                // set it to false when the user is logged out

                editor.putString("CostamarId",CostamarId);

                // Commit the edits!
                editor.commit();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                editor1.putString("CostamarId",CostamarId);



                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ForgetPasswordActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("CUSTID",CostamarId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                toast("Json error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            toast("Unknown Error occurred");
            //progressDialog.hide();
            //progressDialog.hide();
            //progressDialog.hide();
            //progressDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
```

//                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                headers.put("Authentication", "5vLGpxfO4_FktAkPB0iM--FQh18USYEG7LWWUCbITpGioOZ16QRxe0JuoryqhMHArMcv-lBleaddcJPG3bsj3m94qOke3uq3mXDtvPUZHFkqm9_3Eub7MYlVCudtd8i_qxnFYQFVV8OTNfQ4w01vDjwBvJI2zVUXl8M-A9YfH09sPslbJKyZUBZBNcAqjSOzeIneaNVPH0WWcBP9xx_GvsvISNLWAM1KWlSia5Kb7Glj2ufmdZwl_XE5h1C_0guL5AkJniyLK1cCFjOXH7dgjJA6vjwgc0ol488TyWPWA19sOzsdPrnuzr724-BK3Z84");
                return headers;
            }

```
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }


    };

    strReq.setRetryPolicy(
            new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                    0,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    // Adding request to request queue
    MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

private void toast(String x){ Toast.makeText(this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.login:
            String uName = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            login(uName,pass);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonRegister:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}


public void Login_cancel(View view) {

    editTextUsername.setText("");
    editTextPassword.setText("");
}
```

}

Comment: Okay. Where are you stuck? *"I want"* is not a question, nor describe a problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13910415/3395198

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using CustomStatusGrid.java which is class not activity.
so i am bit confuse how to do the same in this class??

Comment: You have a Context object... Why do you need an Activity?

Comment: You can also use your Singleton class to hold the SharedPreferences, or the user status

Comment: @cricket_007 i am novice developer and i haven't tried anything like this earlier.It would be if you can show me direction.

Comment: Try reading the documentation for the Context class. There is a method that you can get your SharedPreferences object, where your login information exists

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks...