# SharedPreferences If/Else Statement does not work correctly when I force close app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

**Summary of problem:**  When I force close the app by opening task window and swiping it closed my if/else statement is not working properly.  I have the Name Selection Activity as the Default Launcher Activity.  The name selection Activity should only pop up if there are no Shared Prefs, meaning the user has not selected a name yet from the spinner.  But even after the user has selected a name and it is stored in Share Prefs, when I force close the app I still get returned to the name selection activity

**What I have tried** I have tried `if (stringNamePackage.equals(""))` and `if (stringNamePackage == "")` and `if (NAME.equals(""))` and `if (NAME == "")`  At first I thought it was because maybe my Shared Prefs was not saving the name correctly but it is not that, the name still appears correctly when I force close it.  But when I try to add the if/else statment it always just sends me back to the name selection activity regardless if I have a name saved in Shared Prefs or not.  I have spent 4 hours trying to get this to work and I am at my wits end. I also spent hours looking at different stack articles of how to save and retrieve Shared Pref data.   I even tried [how to check the SharedPreferences string is empty or null *android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910156/how-to-check-the-sharedpreferences-string-is-empty-or-null-android) and it is still not working.

**NameSelectionActivity**

```
public class NameSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner nameSpinner;
    String stringNamePackage;
    Button bSaveSelection;
    Context context;
    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    public static String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    public static String NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_selection);
        context = this;
        nameSpinner = findViewById(R.id.horizonNameSpinner);
        stringNamePackage = "";

        //Create the list to populate the spinner
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameList.add("01");
        nameList.add("02");
        nameList.add("03");

        //Array Adapter for creating list
        //adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array., android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        nameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //If User has not selected name, start this activity to allow user to pick Name, else, send user to Main Activity
        //else start MainActivity
        if (stringNamePackage .equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome, please select Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent sendToMainActIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(sendToMainActIntent);
        }


        //Save Selection Button Code
        bSaveSelection = findViewById(R.id.bSaveSelection);
        bSaveSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                //Saves name to SharedPrefs
                saveName();
                //Sends user to MainActivity
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }


    //Stores name selected in SharedPreferences
    public void saveName() {
        SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        //Stores selection in stringNamePackage 
        editor.putString(NAME, stringNamePackage );
        editor.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //Put user selection into String text
        String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        stringNamePackage = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }


}
```

**Main Activity**
 The purpose of this activity case is to send the user back to the name Selection screen when they hit the "Test" button which will erase the shared prefs and hence, trigger the if/else statement and making the user pick a name.  This is how I get and set the Name in Main Activity:

in onCreate

Getting name

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        nameSharedPref = app_preferences.getString(NAME, "");
        name.setText(nameSharedPref);
```

Clearing Name

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                finish();
```

**What I expect:** I expect the user to have to pick a name the first time they boot up the app.  Then, every time they open the app an if/else statement will check if the user has a name or not in Shared Prefs.  If they have a name they will go directly to the Main Activity.  If they don't then they will go back to the Name Selection Activity.

Comment: This is a good time to learn to use a debugger. That would allow you to look at the value of `stringNamePackage`. Also, as for comparing an empty string, this is often preferable: `"".equals(str)`. The Apache Commons Lang is also extremely helpful in for common String operations. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.9

Comment: I changed it to ``if ("".equals(stringDeviceNamePackage)) `` and it is still sending me to the name selection activity after I force kill the app and after the user has already picked a name and stored it in shared prefs

Comment: Are you using the `PreferencesManager` to set a menu or configuration activity or using it to Store arbitrary data, not necessarily link to UI?

Comment: Your name selection activity doesn't seem to be getting the name from shared prefs anywhere... How are you expecting it to not be an empty string?

Comment: Figured it out.  @Racu You bringing up ``PreferencesManager``made me go back and change the code around back.  After 4 hours of reading different solutions things are bound to get mixed up.  ``SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nameSharedPref = sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, null);``  and then I run my ``if (nameSharedPref == null)`` and removed ``PreferencesManager`` altogether and replaced it with `` getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);``

Comment: @Quinn Racu helped out with pointing me in the right direction, I am not sure what point you were trying to get across by stating the obvious; that I needed help :) But I figured it out!

Comment: @Treewallie, great!!! you made me spend 5 minutes editing an answer, that I'm not going to post anymore :-D :-D :-D :-D

Comment: I posted my answer anyway, if that helped you, maybe you want to feed my ego by accepting the answer :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data and store data to your `SharedPreferences` you use this:

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` is used to build "Settings" screens or similar, the first one you use it to store/retrieve arbitrary data not necessarily binded to UI.

Even more if you want to organize your `SharedPreferences` you could append to `getPackageName()` different keys like:

```
getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + ".booleans", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + ".flags", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + ".keys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

each one of them is different file that stores shared preferences, you can ommit the prepending dot `.`, but for naming consistency it'll be better to keep it, there is no really need for the extra keys, but if you have some sort of OCD, that might be "relaxing" ;-).

Then you can use your Android Studio's Device Explorer to browse the shared preferences, they are located under "data/data/*your.package.name*/shared_prefs"

Comment: Perfect.  After many hours of researching solutions, somewhere along the way PreferenceManager was used to try it it out.  Thanks for bringing it up and pointing it out.

Comment: `PreferenceManager` is really powerful if you want to build a "Settings" screen, makes it really easy, but for arbitrary data or make yourself your "Settings" screen `SharedPreferences` is just enough.