# how to check the SharedPreferences string is empty or null

Tags: android

I print the `fotonew` key and it sends a null value. But if `urlfoto` is empty or not, `if (urlfoto! = Null &&! Urlfoto.equals (" "))` goes to this section. Normally he should go to else. The `urlfoto` value goes to the part with a full `urlfoto` value in the case of null but if else. I want to check if the key I pulled is empty or full.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefNew = getContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

urlfoto = sharedPrefNew.getString("fotonew", "");

if(urlfoto!= null && !urlfoto.equals(""))
{
    ...
}
else {
    System.out.println("boş");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check the SharedPreferences string is empty or null \*android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910156/how-to-check-the-sharedpreferences-string-is-empty-or-null-android)

Answer (score 0):

You already declared default value of SharedPreference on Code.

```
urlfoto = sharedPrefNew.getString("fotonew", "");
```

This means if "fotonew" is empty or null sharedPrefNew returns a value ""

Comment: The same problem again. When I print urlfotoyu, it translates to null. But if I check if else, if (urlfoto! = Null &&! Urlfoto.equals ("")) enters this section.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
sharedPrefNew.getString("fotonew", "")
```

is responsible for taking value from shared pref. First parameter is a key, second one is a default value that will be returned if key is not found.
In your case, if there is no object stored for key `"fotoNew"` an empty string will be returned.

You can return `null` :

```
sharedPrefNew.getString("fotonew", null);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The same problem again. When I print urlfotoyu, it translates to null. But if I check if else, if (urlfotoa! = Null &&! Urlfotoa.equals ("")) enters this section.

Comment: String fotoUrl = myPrefs.getString("fotonew",null);
that one will give you either null or a String value from shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
   if (sharedPrefNew.getString("fotonew", "") != null && !sharedPrefNew.getString("fotonew", "").isEmpty()){
       //your code here
    }
```